# Как ввести столбик данных

Tags: python

Как ввести столбик данных, если заранее не известно из скольких строк состоит столбик.

Пример входных данных:

1. 1
2. 9
3. 2
4. 5

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120292/discussion-on-question-by-1macan1----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вывести элементы списка, пронумеровав строки:

```
words = input().split()
for i, word in enumerate(words, 1):
    print(f'{i}. {word}')
```

если ввод:

```
qwe rty ui op asdfghjkl zxc vb nm
```

то распечатает:

```
1. qwe
2. rty
3. ui
4. op
5. asdfghjkl
6. zxc
7. vb
8. nm
```